# HTML Select with jQuery Selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have this code which generates my `select` element

```
    <select id="Select">
@foreach (var obj in Model.Objs)
{
        <option value="@obj.Value" data-1="@obj.Data1" data-2="@obj.Data2" data-3="@obj.Data3">
            @obj.Name
        </option>            
}            
    </select>
```

I have three other `select`s that I am using to filter this select

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Filter1Selected, Model.Filter1Items, new { @onchange = "Filter_Changed()" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Filter2Selected, Model.Filter2Items, new { @onchange = "Filter_Changed()" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Filter3Selected, Model.Filter3Items, new { @onchange = "Filter_Changed()" })
```

And this JS method that does the work

```
function Filter_Changed() {
    var filter1 = $(Filter1Selected).val();
    var filter2 = $(Filter2Selected).val();
    var filter3 = $(Filter3Selected).val();
    $(Select).find("option").show();
    if (filter1 > 0) {
        $(Select).find("option").not("[data-1='" + filter1 + "']").hide();
    }
    if (filter2 > 0) {
        $(Select).find("option").not("[data-2='" + filter2 + "']").hide();
    }
    if (filter3 > 0) {
        $(Select).find("option").not("[data-3='" + filter3 + "']").hide();
    }
}
```

The issue is the filtering does not seem to take proper effect on the Select, some items are filtered correctly for some filter settings, and when I definitely know that there are matching elements that should be shown, and when Chrome dev tools console gets the elements correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just for confirmation, you are writing it like this $("#Filter3Selected").val(); instead of $(Filter3Selected).val();?same goes for $("select").

Comment: Are you sure that `.hide()` is the best way to go? Maybe `.remove()` would be better?

Comment: @Shiv seems to be right about it. can you define an id for one of them and check ?

Comment: `$(Select)` and `$("#Select")` both work... or dont work -.-, 
`$(WithoutIDandQuotes)` works in plenty other parts of my code. 
I want to be able to deselect the filter so `.remove` is not appropriate

Comment: @ColinSteel : I tried the same thing and found the selector having little problem. can you try attribute selecter and check if it works. $("Select option:not([data-3 ='"+ filter3 + "'])")

Comment: Attribute selector was my first attempt, I tried selector `:not()`, jQuery `.not()`, `.find()' etc...

Answer (score 0):

So this selector approach wasn't working, I remember that there is a jQuery or JS method that commits some changes to the DOM because of some delay or something but I cannot remember what it is and neither could Google, each `option` element has the correct `display:none` or `display:inline` but the drop down for the `select` is always empty, even the width of the `select` element is correct that there are items to show.

So I assume this is some limitation of `selects` with 1000s+ entries or Chrome

The result of this work is having to do this, detatching the `option`s from the `select`, working with them and then appending them, with consideration to keep a copy of all the `option` elements when the `select` needs to be re-filtered

```
var options;
function Filter_Changed() {
    var filter1 = $(Filter1Selected).val();
    var filter2 = $(Filter2Selected).val();
    var filter3 = $(Filter3Selected).val();

    if (options != null) { $(Select).html(options); }
    options = $(Select).find("option").detach();
    $(Select).html(options);

    if (filter1 < 253) { options.not("[data-1='" + filter1 + "']").remove(); }
    if (filter2 > 0) { options.not("[data-2='" + filter2 + "']").remove(); }
    if (filter3 > 0) { options.not("[data-3='" + filter3 + "']").remove(); }
}
```